Peer-to-peer file sharing
I built a new computer to replace the one that I am currently using and I would like to set up a peer-to-peer fileshare between the 2 to easily copy files from the old one to the new one. Both are running Ubuntu 24.04 Is there an easy way to set this up without going to a cloud solution or using an external hard drive?

See the Ubuntu to Ubuntu section of this answer.

This question is similar to: How to share files through the local network?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I recommend paying attention to the open source solution Syncthing.
It is available on Windows, Linux, macOS, Android and other less common OS.
The installation and usage guide is available at the link

You can connect both using an Ethernet cable and install and configure Network File System (NFS), choosing one as server and the other as client. Back in the day you had to use an Ethernet crossover cable but now it is not necessary.
On your host install: sudo apt install nfs-kernel-server
For your client: sudo apt install nfs-common
You can use the following GUI to configure: https://github.com/Philippe734/Simple.NFS.GUI

The answers linked in comments are better.

@user10489 I improved my answer.
